# Deleting parts of a large list

Tags: list-manipulation

At present I am running an analysis on economic data. Within the data I was able to identify countries which went through recession. I then calculated for example the average decline rate of GDP during recession. All my results are in the following list:

```
CompleteQuarterlyStatData
```

In this list I had to keep also all the countries which did not go through a recession. So if I ask for the decline rate of Australia during recession I get the following answer:

```
In[1328]:= CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]][[1]][[1]]

Out[1328]= {{"Australia", "AUS", "other countries", "GDP","quarterly data"}, {}}
```

Whereas position 1 (`CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[i]]`) indicates the key figure (in the above example "decline rate during recession"), position 2 (`CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[i]][[j]]`) the economic indicator (in the above example "GDP") and position 3 (`CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[i]][[j]][[k]]`) the country (in the above example "Australia").

(by the way: In total I have nine key figures (so `i` ranges from 1 to 9), 24 economic indicators (`j` ranges from 1 to 24) and 32 countries (`k` ranges from 1 to 32))

As Australia obviously did not got through a recession I want to get rid of all key figures for Australian GDP, which works with the following code:

```
If[
 NumberQ[CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]]] == False, 
 Table[
  Delete[CompleteQuarterlyStatData, i],
  {i,
   Map[
   Part[#, 1 ;; 3] &, 
   Position[CompleteQuarterlyStatData,CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]]]]
  }
 ]
];
```

(Note: Position 2 of `CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]][[1]][[2]]` is `{}` and `CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]][[1]][[2]]` `{"Australia", "AUS", "other countries", "GDP","quarterly data"}`. (see Out[1328]))

So what all countries, which did not go through a recession or a longterm decline, have in common is, that `CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]][[EcoIndicator]][[Country]][[2]]` is always of the value `{}`.

(Note: `CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]]` refers to the key figure "decline rate during recession".)

To get rid of all countries which did not suffer from a longterm decline in a given economic indicator I could wrap `Table` around my if-procedure to go through all economic indicators and countries:

```
Table[
Table[
   If[
 NumberQ[CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]][[EcoIndicator]][[Country]][[2]]] == False, 
 Table[
  Delete[CompleteQuarterlyStatData, i],
  {i,
   Map[
   Part[#, 1 ;; 3] &, 
   Position[CompleteQuarterlyStatData,CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]][[EcoIndicator]][[Country]][[1]]]]
  }
 ]
]
,{Country,Length[CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]][[EcoIndicator]]]}]
,{EcoIndicator,Length[CompleteQuarterlyStatData[[1]]]}];
```

But that does not work. Does anyone has a suggestion?

In fact it would be nice to have something like `Delete[CompleteQuarterlyStatData,ArrayXXX]` whereas `ArrayXXX` represents the position of all countries (which did not go through a longterm decline) within `CompleteQuarterlyStatData`.

---

For better understanding I created an example:

```
list = {
  {
   {{{"Australia","GDP"},{}}, {{"Korea","GDP"},-2.45}, {{"USA","GDP"},-2.34}},
   {{{"Australia","GDP"},2.34}, {{"Korea","GDP"},1.23}, {{"USA","GDP"},1.45}}
  },
  {
   {{{"Greece", "Imports"},3.25}, {{"Turkey","Imports"}, {}}, {{"USA","Imports"},-2.64}},
   {{{"Greece", "Imports"},-1.23}, {{"Turkey","Imports"},3.56}, {{"USA","Imports"},-1.56}}
  }
};
```

The output of `list[[1]][[1]][[1]]` or `list[[2]][[1]][[2]]` matches the pattern `{_,{}}`. In that case I would like not only to delete those parts of list witch matches the pattern `{_,{}}` but also all other key figures which were calculated for the individual country and economic indicator. The result should then be:

```
{
  {
   {{{"Korea","GDP"},-2.45}, {{"USA","GDP"},-2.34}},
   {{{"Korea","GDP"},1.23}, {{"USA","GDP"},1.45}}
  },
  {
   {{{"Greece", "Imports"},3.25}, {{"USA","Imports"},-2.64}},
   {{{"Greece", "Imports"},-1.23}, {{"USA","Imports"},-1.56}}
  }
};
```

The reason: Australia did not go through a longterm decline in GDP, neither did Turkey in imports (if so, all other key figures concerning Australia & GDP or Turkey & imports would be irrelevant for further calculation).

Comment: My +1 is not just because you mentioned GDP in Australia, but it helps :)

Comment: As a general coding style comment, I would suggest that you replace all those sets of double-brackets `[[1]][[1]][[1]]` with the equivalent `[[1, 1, 1]]`. It will be much easier to read.

Comment: I wasn't aware of [[1,1,1]] is equivalent to [[1]][[1]][[1]]. Thanks!

Comment: Not uncommon - when looking at old code of mine I cannot help wincing at those bracket chains (mind you, it worked just fine).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that one of the reasons your code isn't working is that `Delete` doesn't actually modify the original list so during every iteration in your `Table` you're actually working with the original list, not the one that was returned from the previous iteration. One way to solve this is to set `CompleteQuarterlyStatData` to the result of `Delete` in every iteration but a more functional way would be to do something like this instead

```
DeleteCases[CompleteQuarterlyStatData, {_, {}}, {3}]
```

I would suggest that you familiarise yourself with [the use of Patterns in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Patterns.html).

**Edit**

This is probably not the most efficient method, but you could try something like. It seems to work for the example posted by the OP at least.

```
list = {
        {
         {{{"Australia", "GDP"}, {}}, {{"Korea", "GDP"}, -2.45}, 
          {{"USA", "GDP"}, -2.34}}, 
         {{{"Australia", "GDP"}, 2.34}, {{"Korea", "GDP"}, 1.23}, 
          {{"USA", "GDP"}, 1.45}}}, 
        {
         {{{"Greece", "Imports"}, 3.25}, {{"Turkey", "Imports"}, {}}, 
          {{"USA", "Imports"}, -2.64}}, 
         {{{"Greece", "Imports"}, -1.23}, {{"Turkey", "Imports"}, 3.56}, 
          {{"USA", "Imports"}, -1.56}}
        }
       };   

DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ Cases[list, {a_, {}} :> {a, _}, {3}], {3}]
```

> ```
> {
>    {
>     {{{"Korea", "GDP"}, -2.45}, {{"USA", "GDP"}, -2.34}}, 
>     {{{"Korea", "GDP"}, 1.23}, {{"USA", "GDP"}, 1.45}}}, 
>    {
>     {{{"Greece", "Imports"}, 3.25}, {{"USA", "Imports"}, -2.64}}, 
>     {{{"Greece", "Imports"}, -1.23}, {{"USA", "Imports"}, -1.56}}
>    }
>   }
> ```

Comment: @John I can't see your example. Maybe you can post it in your original question.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve the problem, as I don't only want to delete elements which match the pattern {_, {}}. Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @John please see edit.

Comment: Seems to me if it works. The first results look good and I hope there won't be any exceptions.

Comment: I assume that `{3}` in `DeleteCases`and `Cases` stands for the level specification within `list`?

Comment: @John yes, that's right.